# Google maps api Directions User defined Steps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I have a google map service with the stores mapped on it.
I also have directions service (then you define two addresses or more and it shows you a way on this map, see google map api directions). So I waте to show the nearest stores to this way. Of course it could be the store located in the next streat of my way, so it also should be included to the list.

So far I just found only an array of steps in the directions object which I get from google maps api. But these steps are predefined by google, so they can be too close one each to other and they also can be too far (if a part of your route is a highway or there is no any special steps on your way etc.)

So, what I want to do. I want to make my own steps on the line that I get from google directions (for example to put these steps on my line every 500 meeters etc.), and after that to search every step for any stores around 200 meeters.

Is it possible to do? I cannot find any solution of this idea in internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

Here it is if somebody will get the same problem

```
for (var i = 0; i < directionResult.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: directionResult.routes[0].overview_path[i],
        map: myMap
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @DolceVita where do you specify the distance? I ran this code, and only retrieved a list of default directions of Google API.